# Display all Posts and only certain Custom Post Types with meta fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, homepage, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to display all posts and only certain custom posts on the homepage.

Essentially: `(post_type = post) OR (post_type = exhibition AND featured = 1)`

I'm stuck with the actual implementation though.

`pre_get_posts` and `$query->set(...);` don't seem to allow logic on the `post_type`, it seems you can only set `(post OR exhibition) AND (featured=1)`.

I'd rather not have to set `featured=1` on every single post.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify `OR` or `AND` on arbitrary `WP_Query` arguments. Meta and Taxonomy queries let you specify `OR` or `AND` for those queries, but other arguments are all combined (`post_type` is a property of the post, not meta, so a meta query won't help). Refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for each of the possible arguments and how to use them.

You'll see that some arguments support an Array as a value, like `post_type`, so you can pass `'post_type' => ['post', 'exhibition']` and it will get both `exhibition` and `post` posts.

However when you're doing this you can't specify that another argument or meta query only apply to one of the post types.

If the posts are going to be displayed separately, then you could just perform 2 queries. Otherwise you will need to query the database directly with [`wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). That would look something like:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT 
        posts.* 
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts posts 
    LEFT JOIN 
        $wpdb->postmeta ON 
            ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' )
    WHERE
        posts.post_type = 'post' OR
        ( posts.post_type = 'exhibition' AND postmeta.meta_value = '1' )
    "
);
```

I haven't tested it, but that's the rough idea. You'd need to add SQL for the posts count and any ordering as well.

There's also the [`posts_where`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) and [`posts_join`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_join/) filters you could use to *modify* the existing query for the posts. That's a little bit more involved, but if you need to modify the main query or are relying on other `WP_Query` arguments and don't want to have to rewrite their SQL then you should use those filers.

Comment: Almost always avoid using wpdb to do modifying or querying of posts, get_posts, or get_post_meta should be first stop when dealing in post issues... Great answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return custom posts, use this.

```
$args = array(
          'numberposts'=> -1,
          'post_type' => 'custom post type name'
        );
$results = get_posts( $args ); //get all post data results

foreach ($results as $rel){//sift through data and find relevant meta data
  $ret = get_post_meta($rel->ID,'meta_field',true);
  if(!empty($ret)){
      //do something with this post data
  }

}
```

This will get all the posts that fall under that post type. Hopefully this helps get you started.